# Python 3: how to tests exceptions within with?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, nose, python-mock

I have problems to test exceptions which would be raised within a with in python 3.4. I just can't get the tests run for this peace of code:

```
import logging
...
class Foo(object):
    ...
    def foo(self, src, dst):
        try:
            with pysftp.Connection(self._host, username=self._username, password=self._password) as connection:
                connection.put(src, dst)
                connection.close()
        except (
                ConnectionException,
                CredentialException,
                SSHException,
                AuthenticationException,
                HostKeysException,
                PasswordRequiredException
        ) as e:
            self._log.error(e)
```

And this is how I want to test it:

```
import logging
...
class TestFoo(TestCase):
    @parameterized.expand([
        ('ConnectionException', ConnectionException),
        ('CredentialException', CredentialException),
        ('SSHException', SSHException),
        ('AuthenticationException', AuthenticationException),
        ('HostKeysException', HostKeysException),
        ('PasswordRequiredException', PasswordRequiredException),
    ])
    @patch('pysftp.Connection', spec_set=pysftp.Connection)
    def test_foo_exceptions(self, _, ex, sftp_mock):
        """
        NOTE: take a look at:
              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014904/mocking-python-class-in-unit-test-and-verifying-an-instance
              to get an understanding of __enter__ and __exit__
        """
        sftp_mock.return_value = Mock(
            spec=pysftp.Connection,
            side_effect=ex,
            __enter__ = lambda self: self,
            __exit__ = lambda *args: None
        )
        foo = Foo('host', 'user', 'pass', Mock(spec_set=logging.Logger))
        foo.foo('src', 'dst')
        self.assertEqual(foo._log.error.call_count, 1)
```

But it fails - output:

```
Failure
...
AssertionError: 0 != 1
```

Comment: Do you mean 'exceptions in `pysftp.Connection` instantiation' or when calling `connection.something()`?

Comment: What do you mean by *with a `with`*? What raises the exception? The context manager you create for use in `with`? Or is the context manager supposed to handle an exception raised in the block managed by `with`?

Comment: You are raising the exception as a side-effect of *creating* your context manager (the `pysftp.Connection(..)` call raises it). The `with` statement never gets to use it as a context manager, nor does the block managed by `with` ever get executed. So your code is correctly exercising the `try:...except ..` statement, but you don't need any context manager knowledge. What is going wrong then is how the logger is called it appears.

Comment: What exactly does `Foo.__init__` do with the 4th positional argument? Is it called or just stored straight as `self._log`?

Comment: @ForceBru I mean exception in pysftp.Connection

Comment: @MartijnPieters the 4th argument is just stored

Comment: @LarsGrundei: It turns out to be moot; see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sftp_mock.return_value` object is never called, so the `side_effect` is never triggered and no exception is raised. It would only be called if the *return value* of `pysftp.Connection(...)` was itself called again.

Set the side effect *directly on the mock*:

```
sftp_mock.side_effect = ex
```

Note that now the `pysftp.Connection(...)` expression raises the exception and it no longer matters that the return value of that expression would have been used as a context manager in a `with` statement.

Note that your exceptions will complain about not getting any arguments; pass in *instances* of your exceptions, not the type:

```
@parameterized.expand([
    ('ConnectionException', ConnectionException('host', 1234)),
    # ... etc.
])
```

Comment: results in: `TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'host' and 'port'`

Comment: @LarsGrundei: ah, your *exception* raises that; you'll have to provide instances, not the class. You can reproduce that error with `raise pysftp.ConnectionException`, for example.